# What's the best way to force my container class to only accept objects that implement IComparable?

Tags: c#

I am learning C#.  Doing the below exercises to make use of features.

I have this class acting as my container:

```
class myContainer<T> : List<T>
```

When I add this struct to the container it works fine because it has an implementation of IComparable

```
interface bla<T> : IComparable<T> {}
struct IString : bla<IString>
```

When I add a class that has not implemented IComparable through an interface or directly, I get an error at runtime if I do something like Sort()

What's the best way to force my container class to only accept objects that implement IComparable ?

thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
class myContainer<T> : List<T>
    where T : IComparable<T>
{
    ...
}
```

If possible, you might want to also consider supporting `IComparable` (the non-generic version) for your class.

[This MSDN article on generic constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28VS.80%29.aspx#csharp_generics_topic4) has more information on the `where` expression.

Comment: David. +1 if you include a link to an explination of generic contraints e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(VS.80).aspx#csharp_generics_topic4

Comment: @Binary Worrier: Happy to oblige. :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can restrict via a where clause like this:

```
class myContainer<T> : List<T> where T : IComparable<T>
```

Answer (score 1):

class mycontainer  : List where T : IComparaable

Require T to implement IComparable. Look up the WHERE keyword for this ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a where to your class to constrain the type.

So you need something like this:

```
class myContainer<T> : List<T>
    where T: IComparable<T>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `where` keyword to put a constraint on the generic type parameter:

```
class myContainer<T> : List<T> where T : IComparable<T> {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Implement a custom object for your container that enforces a constraint:

public class ContainerList : IList
   where T : IComparable
{
}